# VB.NET and Program Architecture

Tags: vb.net

I would like to write a program like sales in which there's two table to insert i.e: SaleHeader Table and SaleDetails Table.  These two tables have (one to many) relationship. When I insert to SaleDetails Table I need to get SaleHeaderID to insert at SaleDetails.

Now I am using a stored procedure to insert SaleHeader information and to get back SaleHeaderID and I use query statements to insert SaleDetail information.

Any one can advise me for more effective way to insert to those two tables (having one to many relationship) ? Help me! Thanks in advance all.

Comment: this really has nothing to do w/vb....

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a `Guid` for the `SaleHeaderID`. Then you can generate the new id in your stored procedure (using [`NEWID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276822(SQL.80).aspx)) before inserting the header record, and then you will also know the id so you can use it for the details.

Comment: How about using SELECT IDENTITY() , because my SaleHeaderID is bigint Type? I would like to know is the other approach besides using stored procedure for SaleHeader Table